# What is gcc serial?

Tags: gcc

I am compiling some benchmarks, and it says that I can try the option gcc-serial instead of only gcc, can anyone please explain the difference between gcc and gcc serial?.

The place where that appears is [here](http://parsec.cs.princeton.edu/download/tutorial/parsec-tutorial.pdf) and it is mentioned for example in the slide 71. It is mentioned in more places but in none of them say what is gcc-serial.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slides refer to a tool from Stanford (PARSEC) meant to benchmark multithreaded shared memory programs -- a.k.a. parallel programs.  In many cases, "serial" is the opposite of "parallel":

```
$ cat config/gcc-serial.bldconf
#!/bin/bash
#
# gcc-serial.bldconf - file containing global information necessary to build
#                      the serial versions of the PARSEC programs with gcc
#
# Copyright (C) 2006, 2007 Christian Bienia

# Global configuration is identical to multi-threaded version
source ${PARSECDIR}/config/gcc.bldconf
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of `gcc-serial`, and I've used `gcc` for quite a while.  Can you clarify more precisely what your benchmarks are telling you?  Maybe you meant "`gcc -serial`" (with a space after `gcc` and before `-serial`)?  Even in that, case though, I still don't know, since I can't find any mention of a `-serial` option in my `gcc` manual.

One version of `gcc` I'm using has the `-mserialize-volatile` and `-mno-serialize-volatile` options, which enable and disable respectively the generation of code that ensures the sequential consistency of [volatile memory accesses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have updated my question with the place where I saw that

Answer (score 1):

From the slides, it seems to be a configuration name for the benchmarking tool, not a command you should use. It probably means some special way of using gcc when the tool is used.